# For non $\sigma$-finite $d\mu$, integrable $f$, and $A_f = \{ f > 0 \}$, show that $\mathcal{V}(E) = \int_E \chi_{A_f}(x) \, d\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f \ge 0$ be integrable for a measure $d\mu$ e.g. $\int f \, d\mu < \infty$.
>
> Here $d\mu$ will not in general be $\sigma$-finite.
>
> Let $A_f = \{ x : f(x) > 0 \}$. Show that the set function
>   \begin{align*}
>   \mathcal{V}(E) &= \int_E \chi_{A_f}(x) \, d\mu \\
> \end{align*}
>
> is a $\sigma$-finite measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of sets corresponding to the measure $d\mu$.
>
> Roughly speaking, this shows that $A_f$ is $\sigma$-finite.

One simple example of a non $\sigma$-finite measure would be the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, any integrable $f$ has a finite number of non-zero elements, such that $\mathcal{V}(E)$ for any $E$ would be finite and therefore $\sigma$-finite.

But I really don't see how to prove this or go about proving this in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mu ( \{x:f(x) \geq \frac 1 n\}) \leq  n\int_{\{x:f(x) \geq \frac 1 n\}} fd\mu\leq n\int f d\mu <\infty
$$ for all $n$. Hence
$$
\nu  \{x:f(x) \geq \frac 1 n) <\infty
$$ for each $n$. The union of the sets here is $A_f$.

Comment: How did you get $\mu ( \{x:f(x) \geq \frac 1 n\})\leq n\int f d\mu$? Is that a theorem?

Comment: I have added one more step. Integbral of $f$ is greater than or equal to integral over a subset. On the subset $f\geq \frac 1 n$ we have $f \geq \frac 1 n$. Integrte both sides w.r.t. $\mu$